# Manipulate the value within Show Feature Count

Tags: qgis, statistics

issue with Show Feature Count:

Please check images..

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I think the reason you are getting down voted is that you posted your question as a series of images. This makes it really hard for future users with a similar question to search for it. Having images is great, but having a text question is essential.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. "Show feature count" does exactly what it says: it shows the total number of features. It doesn't allow you to see other stats in the Layer panel.

There are a number of other ways to display Statistics in QGIS.

- The Statistics panel, as you've already figured out.
- Display the sum as a label.
- The FS3 plugin: "Quickly generate, display, and compare basic statistics and graphs for numeric and text fields of vector layer(s)" -plugin description

None of these are exactly what you're asking for, because QGIS doesn't have that feature.